# Omission of second " is". Style or grammar rule?

Tags: ellipsis

It's the second time I've seen writers omit the second " is" in a sentence:

> Because **the** **effort** **is** **hard** and **the result** **unsparing**, it isn’t obvious that writing like Boo’s has a future.

Is it personal style or grammar rules?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omitting such a repeated verb is optional, neither required nor forbidden by grammar rules. It is quite common, and I suspect growing more so. The choice is a matter of style.